# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 14: invalid start byte

Tags: robotframework

I am new to python. I am using Selenium library to automate one use case.I have to upload a file from my local. I want this path of the file to be absolute.

Below is the mentioned piece of code I have written:

```
${curdir}= OperatingSystem.Get File${CURDIR}\\..\\ImportFiles\\PUIMeasure_Report.xlsx

Choose File    //*`[@id='importMeasureForm:measureUploadFileComponent:file']    ${curdir}.
```

The file is correctly located. When i run it, it is showing the following error in log file.

> ${curdir} = OperatingSystem . Get File
>   C:\Users\aha8kor\eclipse-workspace\ActionPlanSmokeTest\Tests\Resources\PO\..\ImportFiles\PUIMeasure_Report.xlsx
>
> Start / End / Elapsed: 20180420 11:16:10.518 / 20180420 11:16:10.523 /
>   00:00:00.005
>
> 11:16:10.519 INFO Getting file
>   'C:\Users\aha8kor\eclipse-workspace\ActionPlanSmokeTest\Tests\Resources\ImportFiles\PUIMeasure_Report.xlsx'.
>
> 11:16:10.523 FAIL UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte
>   0xa5 in position 14: invalid start byte

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrdmR.png)

Comment: have u try this one as your path  ${path}= 
   ${CURDIR}\..\ImportFiles\PUIMeasure_Report.xlsx

Comment: Yes, i have tried but still no luck. The problem is that in log file i can see that it tries to get the file from a location. The location is displaying correctly, but next line it is showing the Unicode decode error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the  solution after too many attempts.
Instead of using "get file" which resulted in encoding and decoding the issue, I gave the path directly in "Choose File" keyword.

Choose File    //*[@id='importMeasureForm:measureUploadFileComponent:file']    ${CURDIR}\ImportFiles\PUIMeasureReport.xlsx

I had messed up the path previously.This is just a workaround to avoid such kind of an issue.

I still want to know as how can i handle such encoding decoding issues with "Get File" method. 
Thanks in advance.